# How can I render a heterogeneous collection of models using special partials contained at a specified path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial-views

I have partials created for several of my models. However, I also have a search controller that I would like to use different partials for. The reason for this is that the search controller displays a collection of various model types, so the partials I want to use in that view also display the model name.

I'm currently rendering with this line in views/search/index.hmtl.erb: `<%= render @results %>`.

Is there a way I can easily tell the call to render using the partials contained in the `views/search` directory? Or should I do this differently altogether?

Comment: What are you using for search?

Comment: @MarkMerritt Sunspot: http://sunspot.github.io